# CSS3 Display other element on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm here trying to display a list item on hovering an anchor tag. [**How to affect other elements when a div is hovered**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) - tried using this post but I couldn't succeed.

I'm here trying this with only pure CSS.

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KA5Tg/).

And below is the code.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <a class="user" href="#">Brett</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
body {
    font-size: 50px;
}
.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    /*color: #fff;*/
}
.user {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: 11%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.menu a:hover .menu ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;
    /*color: #000;*/
    /*-webkit-transition: color 1s;*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [adjacent siblings selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

`.menu a:hover + ul` instead of `.menu a:hover .menu ul`

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KA5Tg/3/)

Comment: Once the element is visible i can't move my mouse on to it. It's getting disappeared as soon as the mouse get's away from the anchor tag because of the hover effect. How can i make it to place my mouse on to it?

Comment: Try using `.menu:hover a + ul`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the adjacent siblings selector:

```
.menu > a:hover + ul
```

Also, there's something wrong with your property `-webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;` as it is preventing the menu from appearing.

http://jsfiddle.net/KA5Tg/4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `.menu a:hover + ul` this worked for me and even the transition is working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Here [is update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KA5Tg/5/), Position is not correct for menu but its working on hover.

I have updated css as:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: 11%;  
    display :none;
}
.menu a:hover + ul {
    display :block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: visibility 1s, opacity 1s;

}
```